# awk to get the IP and Name from nslookup output

Tags: awk

I have a file which is `File1.txt` and hold some IP address.

```
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
```

Usually when we used to do `nslookup` it provide name resolution against that IP via DNS as below..

```
# nslookup 192.168.1.2
Server:         192.168.1.1
Address:        192.168.1.1#53

2.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa      name = rob.example.com.
```

As we see the above output provides many information, However i would like only the Name to be captured against the give IP('s) hence using awk to get the desired result.

I have Below for loop against teh IP list and it's Just getting the Names.

```
cat File1.txt`;do nslookup $i | awk '/name/{print $4}';done

rob.example.com
tom.example.com
tony.example.com
```

Is there a possible one liner to get he IP and names both to be printed like without having a written into a script file.

```
192.168.1.2  rob.example.com
192.168.1.3  tom.example.com
192.168.1.4  tony.example.com
```

Though the bash solution  is there..

```
#!/bin/bash

iplist="File1.txt"

while read -r ip; do
       printf "%s\t%s\n" "$ip" "$(dig +short -x $ip)"
   done < "$iplist"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** In case OP's Input_file is having IPs in it then following may help you.

```
while read ip
do
    nslookup "$ip" | awk -v ip="$ip" '/name/{print substr($NF,1,length($NF)-1),ip}'
done < "Input_file"
```

***Explanation:*** This is only for explanation purposes, for running code please use above code only.

```
while read ip
    ##Starting a while loop which will read OP's Input_file which will have IPs in it. ip is the variable which has its value.
do
    nslookup "$ip" | awk -v ip="$ip" '/name/{print substr($NF,1,length($NF)-1),ip}'  
    ##using nslookup and passing variable ip value to it, to get specific IPs server name and passing it to awk then.
    ##In awk command setting up a variable named ip whose value is shell variable ip value and then checking if a line is having name in it if yes then printing the last column value leaving last DOT. 
done < "Input_file"
    ##Mentioning Input_file name here which should be passed.
```

---

---

Could you please try following.(considering that your Input_file is having server names on it)

```
while read ip
do
   nslookup "$ip" |  awk '/Name:/{val=$NF;flag=1;next} /Address:/ && flag{print $NF,val;val=""}'
done < "Input_file"
```

Comment: @pygo, when I test it on my machine by giving some server names in Input_file then it is giving me proper format.

Comment: are you taking Server names or IP's

Comment: pygo, I have taken server names in Input_file.

Answer (score 1):

Ah! Its pretty Simple while going through awk manual i got it with awk variable ie straight forward..

```
$ for i in `cat File1.txt`;do nslookup $i | awk -v var=$i  '/name =/{print var "\t", $4}';done

192.168.1.2  rob.example.com
192.168.1.3  tom.example.com
192.168.1.4  tony.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above and several other answers, the following appears to work for the following types of mixed input:

1. domain names
2. IP addresses for reverse lookups
3. blank lines

... and will format the following types of output from `nslookup`:

1. Domains with more than one IP address *(as is common with CDNs in these modern times)*
2. Domains with `cnames`

It will also output the server and port number used, for those who care about such things.

---

Usage:

- One can omit the portions not desired, and it will run on a single command line *(but it is formatted on multiple lines below for readability)*.
- It can easily be modified to output to a `.csv` file, and if run without the final `column` command it will product tab-separated output suitable for direct paste into a spreadsheet application.
- It could also be installed as a `bash` function, for easy re-use.

  - e.g.:

    1. Prefix the first line of the code below with "`nspretty () {` "
    2. Also on the first line, replace "`cat domains.txt`" with "`cat $1`"
    3. Suffix the last line of the code below with " `; }`"
    4. Paste the entire thing into the `bash` shell, or add it to your `.profile` file to automatically load at login.
    5. Run it like this: $`nspretty domains.txt`
  - Mashed together on one line, it's ugly but it works:

    ```sh
    nspretty () { for i in `cat $1`; do nslookup -port=53 $i 127.0.0.1 | awk 'BEGIN {print "\tServer\tPort\tHostname\tAddress\tCanonicalName\n\t------\t----\t--------\t-------\t------------"}; /#/ {split ($2,a,"#"); SERVER=a[1]; PORT=a[2]}; /^Name:\t/ {NAME=$2}; /in-addr.arpa/ {ADDRESS=$1;NAME=$4; print "\t" SERVER "\t" PORT "\t" NAME "\t" ADDRESS }; /canonical name/ {NAME=$1; CNAME=$5; print "\t" SERVER "\t" PORT "\t" NAME "\t" ADDRESS "\t" CNAME}; /^Address: / {ADDRESS=$2; print "\t" SERVER "\t" PORT "\t" NAME "\t" ADDRESS}; END {print }'; done | column -t -n -e ; }`
    ```

> Note: Tested in `bash` on version `5.10.17-v7l+` of `GNU/Linux`
> (`Raspbian`/`Debian 10.9`) running on a `Raspberry Pi`. It may require
> modifications for use on other systems.

---

Example:

Given this sample input file, named `domains.txt`:

```
www.google.com
www.apple.com
www.ibm.com
8.8.8.8
```

```sh
$ for i in `cat domains.txt`; \
    do nslookup -port=53 $i 127.0.0.1 \
    | awk 'BEGIN {print "\tServer\tPort\tHostname\tAddress\tCanonicalName\n\t------\t----\t--------\t-------\t------------"};
           /#/ {split ($2,a,"#"); SERVER=a[1]; PORT=a[2]};
           /^Name:\t/ {NAME=$2};
           /in-addr.arpa/ {ADDRESS=$1;NAME=$4; print "\t" SERVER "\t" PORT "\t" NAME "\t" ADDRESS };
           /canonical name/ {NAME=$1; CNAME=$5; print "\t" SERVER "\t" PORT "\t" NAME "\t" ADDRESS "\t" CNAME};
           /^Address: / {ADDRESS=$2; print "\t" SERVER "\t" PORT "\t" NAME "\t" ADDRESS};
           END {print }'; \
    done \
    | column -t -n -e # Note: -n is a Debian GNU/Linux extension for 'column' - it may not work on every system
```

*(replace `127.0.0.1` with the desired DNS server to use, or omit it entirely to use the system default)*

---

How it works:

1. `BEGIN` prints a header; it only runs once

   - Can be omitted as desired
2. `/#/ {split ($2,a,"#"); SERVER=a[1]; PORT=a[2]};`

   - Finds lines containing `#`
   - Takes the contents of the second 'field' and splits the contents into an array `a`, using `#` as the seperator
   - Assigns the first part `a[1]` to the variable `SERVER`
   - Assigns the second part `a[2]` to the variable `PORT`
3. `/^Name:\t/ {NAME=$2};`

   - Finds lines containing at least one word starting `^` with the text "Name:" followed by a tab *(`\t`)*
   - Assigns the second 'field'/column to the variable `NAME`
4. `/in-addr.arpa/ {ADDRESS=$1;NAME=$4; print "\t" SERVER "\t" PORT "\t" NAME "\t" ADDRESS };`

   - For lines containing the text `in-addr.arpa`
   - Assign the contents of the first column to the variable `ADDRESS`
   - Assign the contents of the 4th column to the variable `NAME`
   - Output a line of formatted text, seperated by tabs *(`\t`)*
5. `/canonical name/ {NAME=$1; CNAME=$5; print "\t" SERVER "\t" PORT "\t" NAME "\t" ADDRESS "\t" CNAME};`

   - Does the same sort of thing as #4, but only for lines containing the text "`cannonical name`"
   - If you don't want `CNAME`s in your output, just leave out this line
6. `/^Address: / {ADDRESS=$2; print "\t" SERVER "\t" PORT "\t" NAME "\t" ADDRESS};`

   - Does the same sort of thing as #4 or #5, but only for lines containing a word starting with "`Address:` " *(there's an intentional space at the end of that string)*
7. `END` prints a footer *(just a blank line here)*; it only runs once

   - Can be omitted as desired
8. The optional last statement, `| column -t -n -e`, uses the `column` command to auto-size the columns for readability.

---

Output for the above example would look something like this:

[image: example DNS output formatted by the above AWK script]